# Can I use the word "debt" to talk about some tasks that I didn't do in due time?

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, vocabulary, spoken-english

Can the word "debt" relate to something not connected to money? More precisely, can I use it to talk about some tasks that I didn't do in due time?

**Example:**
*I had to turn in math homework yesterday, but I completely forgot about that. Plus, I didn't write the essay which was crucial. God, I have so many debts.*

So, is the word "debt" appropriate here?

Comment: **Obligations** is better than 'debts'.

Comment: Okay, thanks! I just wanted to find a word that emphasizes that I didn't do something on time.

Comment: The word 'debt' does not have any meaning of being not on time. An **overdue** debt or obligation is one that should have already been paid or fulfilled.

Comment: @Bonrey A more likely expression is: **I'm so behind with my work**.

Comment: Or just "I'm so far behind"

Comment: Okay, thank you, everyone!